# Can I run .bat file from Pascal?

Tags: cmd, pascal

I wanted to know if it was possible to force CMD to run a file from Pascal program. I want to make a file like this:

```
    `assign(fl, 'run.bat');
     write(fl, 'my cmd commands');
     close(fl);
     [Here I want to force CMD to run my run.bat file]
     end;`
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know whether your pascal implementation supports API calls like CreateProcess and ShellExecute (assuming you're using Windows)?

Comment: Personally I would also add a Rewrite somewhere

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
ExecuteProcess('Run.bat','');
```

You need use SysUtils unit

```
Uses SysUtils;
```

Sorry about my English :(

Comment: If the OP has a `sysutils` unit - you can't assume that from the information provided.

Comment: Then you can also not assume it is windows. It might be Dos or OS/2 (which also support .bat)  And in case of executeprocess you must run it over the shell (by executing cmd.exe/command.com)